# multiple citation of references

Tags: citing

When I use `\cite{ref1, ref2}`, I have a character "?" which appears for ref2 instead of the number of the reference. Do you know how can I cite multiple references using \cite{ref1, ref2} ?

Comment: This should work out of the box. Can you provide a [ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that ](MWE) that shows the problem?

Comment: ref2 is an unknown key and not in the bibfile . Maybe a typo ...

Comment: Be sure to run bibtex and (pdf)latex again.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I have found that some bibliographic styles will not allow a space between the comma and bib key so instead of `\cite{ref1, ref2}` you may need to try `\cite{ref1,ref2}`.